# How to post form data into another data fomat

Tags: python, forms, post, wsgi

- How can I submit form data into another file in python?
- How to get the posted data from the post and how to save it in a data base?
- Should I use wsgi?

  Could you please suggest some example code for that.

Comment: functions, files, and databases are different things. Which are you working with?

Comment: Somehow difficult to guess what exactly you are looking for. Just some hints: Handling requests with python is IMHO best done with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package. If you are looking for a complete solutoin for handling requests (on the server side), data base integration etc, have a look at [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

Comment: suppose i have a file user registration from register.py i want to submit form values into another file named save.py how is it possible